# Cat more files together in a directory by similar names

Tags: loops, awk, filenames, cat

I have files like the following five in the same directory (the names end `.bed and start`chromosome`and have numbers such as`1-5` embedded in the middle; one line of content is shown or each file):

#### chromosome1-5.bed

```
chromosome1     1   21
```

#### chromosome1-2.bed

```
chromosome1     7   30
```

#### chromosome1-9.bed

```
chromosome1     9   75
```

#### chromosome2-1.bed

```
chromosome2     8   50
```

#### chromosome2-5.bed

```
chromosome2     6   23
```

and I try to cat the files, that start with the same number to one single file (so all the files with a leading `1` in the `1-5` etc).

Intended output:

#### chromosome1.bed

```
chromosome1     1   21 
chromosome1     7   30
chromosome1     9   75
```

#### chromosome2.bed

```
chromosome2     8   50 
chromosome2     6   23
```

At this point I try to compare any file of the directory with another with filename.

```
for i in /dir/*; do
    for j in /dir/*; do
        filename=$(basename "$i")
        filename2=$(basename "$j")
        if "$filename" != "$filename2";
        then cat "$i" "$j" > newfile
        fi
    done
done
```

Comment: Regarding the code, you are trying to execute the contents of `$filename` as a command with arguments `=` and `"$filename2"`.  You want to test the strings, which uses the `[` test command:  `if [ "$filename" != "$filename2" ]; then …; fi`.  Note that the spaces around the command name (`[`) and the last argument (`]`) are required.

Comment: How would you know that the output should list `chomosome1-5.bed` before `chromosome1-2.bed`, or does the sequencing not matter?  How many distinct leading numbers are there?  You show `1` and `2`; are the numbers single digits, or can they be many digits long?  Are there leading zeros?  Similarly with the trailing numbers — are they single digit numbers, or can they be longer, and are leading zeros used?  Are there ever blanks or other non-alphanumeric characters apart from `.`, `-`, `_` in the file names?  Are there any other files in the directory that would match `chromosome*-*.bed`?

Comment: The filenames are for example chromosome1-5.bed, chromosome1-2.bed and chromosome1-9.bed. and I try to fit this in one together with just the name chromosome1.bed. 
I tried your suggestion, but I have the message [*: command not found. I try in the code above just to check if the two files are not the same.

Comment: You didn't pay attention to the spacing I showed.

Comment: sequencing isn't important just the first number after chromosome need to be the same, this can be also chomosome31-5.bed or chomosome31-25.bed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
awk '!/^---/ {fname= $1".bed"; print $0 > fname }' *-[0-9].bed
```

**output**

```
cat chromosome1.bed

chromosome1     7   31
chromosome1     1   21
chromosome1     9   75


cat chromosome2.bed

chromosome2     8   50
chromosome2     6   23
```

This script skips lines beginning with `----`, and creates a filename from the first field on remaining lines of data. We append the `".bed"` to that name, and then write (`>`) the complete line to the named file. As the value of `$1` changes, so does the filename.

---

**edit**

As your revised sample data no longer includes `------` lines, this can further be simplified to

```
awk '{fname= $1".bed"; print $0 > fname }' *-[0-9].bed
```

There is no need to filter for lines `----` and that test has been removed. All lines will now automatically be printed into the filename created based on the first field.

---

**edit 2**

To allow to write files to an alternate directory, one approach is to pass in the dir name as a variable, and pre-append it to the `fname` that is being created, i.e.

```
awk -v dir="NewDirectory" '{fname= dir "/" $1 ".bed"; print $0 > fname }' *-[0-9].bed
```

And, of course `"NewDirectory"` could be something like `"$i/$j"`.

IHTH

Comment: Maybe it's was a edit problem. The files don't start with ----.

Comment: @Babi : It would still work, as is. But I will offer alternate. Good luck

Comment: This works in the directory producing new files with the output that I want, but have also the old files. How I can use this awk line and save the outputs in a new directory.
I try this awk '{fname= $1".bed"; print $0 > fname }' *-[0-9].bed  > /newDirectory/
but this doesn't work.

Comment: @Babi : Finished with 2nd edit. Going away for a while. IHTH

Comment: You don't need the `$0` and unless you're going to use it to `close()` files you don't need a variable: `awk -v dir="NewDirectory" '{print > (dir "/" $1 ".bed")}' *-[0-9].bed`

Comment: @EdMorton, I'm aware of that for some, `$0` is redundant, but I prefer "long-hand" versions that add an (every so slight) element of self-documentation ;-). Also, my `uwin` awk was choking on `$1 ".bed"`, so I went with a variable instead. Again, another slight layer of self-documentation. Thanks and good luck to all.

Comment: The choking would be because an unparenthersized expression on the right side of output redirection, e.g. `print > $1 ".bed"`, invokes undefined behavior. Hence the parens, e.g. `print > ($1 ".bed")`.

Comment: @EdMorton : Ah!! Thanks very much for that explanation. I have run into that before and I would usually think "I have done that in the past, why isn't it working now? ... Oh well I'll use a variable instead". Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

While I like the **awk** solution [shelter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/620097/shellter) presents, **make** is an alternative.  Here's a version for GNU make:

```
SRC = $(wildcard chromosome*-*.bed)
TGT = $(sort $(shell echo $(SRC) | sed -E 's/-[0-9]+[.]bed/.bed/g'))

all: $(TGT)

$(TGT): $(SRC)
    cat $(subst .bed,-*.bed,$@) > $@~
    mv $@~ $@

echo: 
    @ls $(SRC)
    @echo targets: $(TGT)
```

The above has every target depend on every source, which is obviously overkill.  If you have many files or they change frequently, you'd probably want to generate correct dependencies.

Advantages:

- Can regenerate particular files by saying e.g. `make chromosome2.bed`.
- Skips regeneration if no files changed or been added.
- Stops on error without leaving a generated file partly done.

Output:

```
$ make
cat chromosome1-*.bed > chromosome1.bed~
mv chromosome1.bed~ chromosome1.bed
cat chromosome2-*.bed > chromosome2.bed~
mv chromosome2.bed~ chromosome2.bed

$ head  chromosome?.bed
==> chromosome1.bed <==
chromosome1     7   30
chromosome1     1   21
chromosome1     9   75

==> chromosome2.bed <==
chromosome2     8   50
chromosome2     6   23
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use globbing?

```
cat chromosome1-* >> chromosome1.bed

cat chromosome2-* >> chromosome2.bed
```

`chromosome2-*` will select all files starting with chromosome2-, you could put this in a loop for each index if you've got too many to do it manually.

Comment: I try this using:
`START=1
END=100
for (( c=$START; c<=$END; c++ ))
do
cat /chromosome"$C"-* >> /chromosome"$C".bed
done` but not works. I have the same message: cat: /chromosome-*: No such file or directory